# SVG text edges change color when scaling

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I've created an SVG filter and applied it to some text. When I scale the text smaller by resizing the browser window, some of the edges of the text have a colored line down one side.

```
<svg
     class="tstx" viewBox="0 0 160 160"
     height="160" width="160"
     style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <defs>
        <filter id="innershadow" x0="-50%" y0="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2" result="blur"/>
            <feOffset dy="3" dx="3"/>
            <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="arithmetic"
                    k2="-1" k3="1" result="shadowDiff"/>
            <feFlood flood-color="grey" flood-opacity="1"/>
            <feComposite in2="shadowDiff" operator="in"/>
            <feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="over"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <g 
       font-family="Verdana" font-size="80" font-weight="bold" 
       stroke="none" fill="#fff" filter="url(#innershadow)">

        <text x="10" y="70">A</text>
        <text x="80" y="70">B</text>

    </g>
</svg>
```

How can I fix this?

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/gatzkerob/pen/BmaPXy)

Move the middle margin right to scale text.

**EDIT:** It looks like I may have fixed the problem - I just don't know why it worked or if it will cause problems later on. I removed the following:

```
<feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="over"/>
```

And the lines disappeared. Is anyone able to explain why?

Comment: What browser were you testing on?  I tried your codepen in Chrome and Firefox and couldn't see any coloured edges.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Chrome - Latest Version with hardware acceleration enabled 
 - Possibly a graphics card issue? I just tried it in Firefox and there were no lines

Comment: This looks fine on Chrome 60/Windows 10 with default flags (there are 5 separate GPU-related flags - so it's good to specify which ones you've changed)